# Creating a new xml file based on a condition using java

Tags: java, xml

I'm passing over all the xml children I Have, and upon detecting in a child, a subchild named: TYPE,
if it has the Value F, it then removed from my object: resultObjectAtt. And what remains in resultObjectAtt is
passed to function which create a new xml file with the passed content.
My question is what can I do, to add the children with F to a new xml file, without changing anything in resultObjectAtt.

```
for (int j = 0; j < childElem.size(); j++) { 
//Number of children under the root

    subChildElem = childElem.get(j).getChildren(); // subchildren

    for (int j2 = 0; j2 < subChildElem.size(); j2++) {
        Name = subChildElem.get(j2).getName(); //subchild name
        Value = subChildElem.get(j2).getValue(); //subchild value
        if(Name.equalsIgnoreCase("TYPE")){
            if(Value.equals("F")){
                resultObjectAtt.getRootElement().getChildren().remove(j);
                convertDocumentToXmlFile("C:\\test.xml", resultObjectAtt);
            }
        }
    }
}



private void convertDocumentToXmlFile(String path, Document doc){

    try {
        XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();

        xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
        xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter(path));

        System.out.println("File Saved!");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create an new [`Document`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) object, then "copy" the [`Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) objects you want, using [`importNode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#importNode(org.w3c.dom.Node,%20boolean)).

Comment: won't that be a heavy operation? I was curious to know if there is a better way than that?

Comment: Well, you can call [`adoptNode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#adoptNode(org.w3c.dom.Node)) instead to "move" the `Node`.